# map if statement if every 3rd include this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am wanting to add  after every 3rd .map item I am wondering if anyone knows of the correct way to do so, As if statements don't work and I am unsure how to achieve this result.

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
    {items.map(item => (
        <MediaCard title={item.title} link={item.url} pic={item.image} category={item.category} tweet={item.TweetIDs}/>
    ))}
    <GoogleAds />
</Grid>
```

I tried to put the if statement in the MediaCard function however realized that was wrong due to I need it to run as the items.map runs.
\

Comment: Strange question... Is that because the items are displayed in a grid or because you genuinely don't want to display everything?

Comment: A simple `for loop` with steps of 3 will work flawless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of map is the index of the item. So you could do:

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
    {
        items.map((item, index) => (
        <>
            <MediaCard title={item.title} link={item.url} pic={item.image} category={item.category} tweet={item.TweetIDs}/>
            {
                ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) && <GoogleAds />
            }
        </>
        ))
    }
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to achieve that. To get the third element, use the modulo % operator. It returns the rest obtained by dividing the number.

First you can use the filter function before the map function:

```
{items.filter((item, index) => index % 3 === 2)
        .map(item => (
            <MediaCard />)}
```

Or return false in map, which will lead to no rendering.

```
items.map((item, index) => (
            index % 3 === 2 && <MediaCard />)}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: @JosephD. What am I suppose to check with my filter function? And returning a falsy element (null, 0, false, NaN) will not render anything. So it does not matter if false or null will be returned.

Comment: I misread. I thought he wanted to filter every third element, not show it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
    {items.map((item, index) => {
        if ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
            return (
                <MediaCard title={item.title} link={item.url} pic={item.image} category={item.category} tweet={item.TweetIDs} />
            )
        }
        else {
          return null;
        } 
    })}
    <GoogleAds />
</Grid>
```